# Internationalization of standalone application

Tags: internationalization

I want to localize my standalone application,ie if we change the GMT time zone as US then all my Application's currency format , time format, numeric format should get change to the US format, so can someone can tell me the essential basic lookups that I need to get through because I am 0 in this Internationalization, so please guide me .... the desktop application I am developing is INDIAN Hospital ERP in java & hibernate for database access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you use Java, regardless if this is desktop, mobile or web application, what you should care about is using Locale(s). That is, you should detect them.

If you want to change the data to be Locale aware, you need to use the following (Java 7)

```
// Detecting locale in desktop application
Locale fmtLocale = Locale.getDefault(LocaleCategory.FORMAT);
DateFormat dateFmt = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
    DateFormat.DEFAULT, DateFormat.DEFAULT, fmtLocale);
dateFmt.setTimeZone(theTimeZone); // ommited
Date now = new Date();
String formattedDate = dateFmt.format(now);
// do something with formatted date
// Similarily for numbers, percentages and currencies
NumberFormat numberFmt = NumberFormat.getInstance(fmtLocale);
NumberFormat percentFmt = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance(fmtLocale);
NumberFomrat currencyFmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(fmtLocale);
```

You should not, under any circumstances tied this up with time zone. For instance, there are several time zones in the US, so it really does not make sense. You would have to check if this is US time zone (which won't be the easiest thing to do) and do something awful like assign default Locale (which will assign Locale for *every* program running on this JVM, very bad idea).
Just detecting the Locale should be sufficient (this is actually the i18n best practice).